# Getting the used Selenium version in Groovy project

Tags: java, maven, selenium, groovy, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Selenium in my Groovy application as a Maven dependency. Now I'm looking for a way to log the used Selenium Version to the console. 
I tried this:

```
  BuildInfo info = new BuildInfo();
  def infoString = info.toString();
```

But `infoString` only contains:

"Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'".

I also tried reading the version from the classpath of the project and though this works in a Java project in a groovy project the classpath no longer contains the used selenium version.

In a java project the `infoString` also contains the used version, revision etc.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     BuildInfo info = new BuildInfo();
     String infoString = info.toString();
     System.out.format(infoString);
```

Instead of using def which is a groovy variable, i choose to use a string.
Then i used System.out.format to log it in the console which is the eclipse console for me.

Comment: Hiya there, while this may well answer the question, please be aware that other users might not be as knowledgeable as you. Why don't you add a little explanation as to why this code works? Thanks!

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer, but unfotunately this doesn't solve the issue. The infoString is still the same as above.